# How can I redirect from node.js ? res.redirect doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, authentication, github

I am trying to authenticate with Github, and I am following the flow of [their docs](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/).

In my client side (React.js) I have a button that calls my api/github route:

client:

```
  <button onClick={githubAuth} className="social 
   github"><i className="fab fa-github"></i>    Log in 
   with Github</button>


const githubAuth = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
          await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/oauth/github')
        }
        catch(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
router.get('/github', async (req,res) => {
    try{
      res.redirect('https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize/?client_id='+config.get('githubClientId'))
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err.response)
    }
})
```

the problem is that my redirect doesn't work.
in my F12 console I am getting this message :

"xhr.js:178 GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize/?client_id=d5182c08d55e334124a5 net::ERR_FAILED"

How can I normally redirect my client page to the Github authorization page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the user browser to visit your GitHub OAuth in:
`'http://localhost:5000/api/oauth/github'`

From there, express will redirect your user to the appropriate GitHub page for authorization.

```
const githubAuth = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const githubOAuthURL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/oauth/github';
        let githubTab = window.open(githubOAuthURL, '_blank');
        githubTab.focus();
    }
```

Comment: thank for your comment. In your case, its opened a new tab for redirecting the page, if i want to redirect from the same page that i pressed the button? @Yoel

Comment: Replace `_blank` with `_self`